# How to array_merge_recursive() an array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, merge

I am just starting to understand how `array_merge_recursive()`works.

Can someone tell me how to use this php function with an array?

I am trying to do the following:

```
$ars[] = array("name_a" => array("color" => array("red")));
$ars[] = array("name_a" => array("color" => array("green", "blue")));
$ars[] = array("name_b" => array("color" => array("green", "tangerine")));
$ars[] = array("name_c" => array("color" => array("purple", "blue","red")));
$ars[] = array("name_c" => array("color" => array("green", "blue","green","beige")));
$ars[] = array("name_b" => array("color" => array("green", "blue","yellow")));

$result = array_merge_recursive($ars);
```

for some reason that I don't know, that does not work. The only way it is working for me is as follows:

```
$ars1 = array("name_a" => array("post_id" => array("red")));
$ars2 = array("name_a" => array("post_id" => array("green", "blue")));
$ars3 = array("name_b" => array("post_id" => array("green", "blue")));
$ars4 = array("name_c" => array("post_id" => array("green", "blue","red")));
$ars5 = array("name_c" => array("post_id" => array("green", "blue","green","beige")));
$ars6 = array("name_b" => array("post_id" => array("green", "blue","yellow")));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ars1,$ars2,$ars3,$ars4,$ars5,$ars6);
```

So, how can I put an array inside the `array_merge_recursive();` function?

Comment: Quoting from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php): `array_merge_recursive — Merge __two or more arrays__ recursively` (my emphasis).... you're trying to merge a single array..... explain what you're trying to achieve

Comment: At a guess: `$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $ars);` See [demo](http://ideone.com/GzaDjy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `array_merge_recursive();` or any other function with an array mapped as args you can use:

`$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $ars);`

Starting with PHP 5.6 there is a special operator for that:

`$result = array_merge_recursive(...$ars);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question didn't you?

array_merge_recursive() requires two parameters of array type so that you can "merge" them. what exactly are you merging with one array?